# Looking for architectures to develop massive multiplayer game server

Tags: architecture, mmo, client-server

Hello all Where can I find architectures and examples of building massive multiplayer game server Does the does the concept of building it on top of libenevt is right ? or I need to think more on thread per connection ? im targeting to web players playing from flash / html5 clients . Thanks

Comment: What kind of numbers are you thinking about (per shard online at the same time?)

Comment: "Thread-per-connection" and "massively multiplayer" don't go together.

Comment: so what do you mean its not going to go together ?
i guess the numbers are as high as can i go with min cpu+ram

Comment: Threads don't scale well beyond a few hundred connections. If you want to hit server concurrency >500, you need single-process async networking models more like libevent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are thinking about a real time MMO and not a social MMO, it would definitely be worth taking a look at [MV3D](http://www.mv3d.com/) which is open source. It is mainly geared towards having a less lightweight client than flash, but I'm currently using it to make a browser based game and it's going well.

For a social MMO, I'd suggest building the server on the web framework of your choice rather than making your own server application. You can architect and scale your server similar to how large websites do it. There are plenty of online resources for doing that.

For either way, a great place to look is highscalability.com. In particular, here's some info on [Playfish's architecture](http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/9/21/playfishs-social-gaming-architecture-50-million-monthly-user.html).